# Poisson distribution concrete example

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

What is an example of a Poisson distributed random variable with parameter $\lambda  > 0$?

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia's entry on the [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution):

> For instance, a call center receives an average of 180 calls per hour,
> 24 hours a day. The calls are independent; receiving one does not
> change the probability of when the next one will arrive. The number of
> calls received during any minute has a Poisson probability
> distribution with mean 3: the most likely numbers are 2 and 3 but 1
> and 4 are also likely and there is a small probability of it being as
> low as zero and a very small probability it could be 10. Another
> example is the number of decay events that occur from a radioactive
> source during a defined observation period.

---

**UPDATE**

I don't quite understand what a more mathematical example would be. Perhaps if you have a discrete random variables $X,Y,Z$ with the pmfs
$$
\begin{split}
f_X(k) &= \frac{1/e}{k!}, \quad k \ge 0 \\
g_Y(k) &= \frac{e^{k-e}}{k!}, \quad k \ge 0 \\
h_Z(k) &= \frac{1}{e^\pi} \frac{\pi^k}{k!}, \quad k \ge 0
\end{split}
$$
then $X \sim \mathcal{P}(1), Y \sim \mathcal{P}(e)$ and $Z \sim \mathcal{P}(\pi)$.

Comment: Is there also a more mathematical example, except the real-life examples for function X?

Comment: @pba not sure what that would mean, but please see the update.

Comment: The "more mathematical" way the Poisson($\lambda$) distribution appears is as the $n \to \infty,p=\lambda/n$ limit of the binomial distribution. It is worth thinking about how this compares to the Poisson process.

Comment: For a mathematical way, I was referring to a concrete formula for the random variable X.

Comment: If Ian's hint isn't concrete enough perhaps the following is ? Draw independent [exponentially distributed](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4208992/949989) waiting times $\sigma_i$ (these are the times between two calls to the center). $\tau_n=\sigma_1+...+\sigma_n$ is the time of the $n$-th call. The number of calls that have arrived within, say, one day will be Poisson distributed. With the link I have given you can even simulate this.

Comment: There's always a "concrete formula" for any 1D random variable as $Q(U)$ where $Q$ is the quantile function and $U$ is uniform($0,1$) distributed.